# Error while retrieving transaction count

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, web3j, infura, java

I am trying to retrieve the total transaction count of an address using java, web3j and Infura as the Ethereum client. My code is as below:

```
EthGetTransactionCount txnCount = web3j.ethGetTransactionCount(infuraAccessToken
            ,DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).sendAsync().get();
    BigInteger nonce = txnCount.getTransactionCount();       
    System.out.println("Transaction Count "+ nonce);
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.web3j.exceptions.MessageDecodingException: Value must be in format 0x[1-9]+[0-9]* or 0x0     
    at org.web3j.utils.Numeric.decodeQuantity(Numeric.java:32)  
    at org.web3j.protocol.core.methods.response.EthGetTransactionCount.getTransactionCount(EthGetTransactionCount.java:13)  
    at com.mycompany.hellospring.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:46)
```

I am unable to find any solution related to this till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was giving the access token provided by Infura in place of the address. So now I'm not getting the message decode exception. However, now O is always being returned as the transaction count which is incorrect.